# Not able to install pg gem with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have this dreaded error:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

There is greatly delaying my work. Before this error comes this:

```
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
compiling pg_binary_decoder.c
compiling pg_binary_encoder.c
compiling pg_coder.c
pg_coder.c:216:34: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        res = this->dec_func(this, val, RSTRING_LEN(argv[0]), tuple, field, ENCODING_GET(argv[0]));
              ~~~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1007:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_coder.c:216:34: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        res = this->dec_func(this, val, RSTRING_LEN(argv[0]), tuple, field, ENCODING_GET(argv[0]));
              ~~~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1008:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_connection.c
compiling pg_copy_coder.c
pg_copy_coder.c:228:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1007:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_copy_coder.c:228:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1008:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

I'm wonbdering where these errors are coming from, it seems to me it can't convert something, perhaps in my rails database structure?

```
pg_copy_coder.c:534:23: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                input_len = end_ptr - start_ptr;
                          ~ ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
compiling pg_errors.c
compiling pg_record_coder.c
pg_record_coder.c:196:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1007:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_record_coder.c:196:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1008:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_result.c
compiling pg_text_decoder.c
compiling pg_text_encoder.c
```

The same error again, a conversion loss stopping it from installing postgresql:

```
pg_text_encoder.c:194:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        len = out - start;
                            ~ ~~~~^~~~~~~
pg_text_encoder.c:406:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                return optr - out;
                ~~~~~~ ~~~~~^~~~~
pg_text_encoder.c:410:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                return 2 + RSTRING_LEN(*intermediate) * 2;
                ~~~~~~ ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_text_encoder.c:617:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        nr_elems = RARRAY_LEN(value);
                 ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1070:23: note: expanded from macro 'RARRAY_LEN'
#define RARRAY_LEN(a) rb_array_len(a)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
compiling pg_tuple.c
pg_tuple.c:482:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        num_fields = RARRAY_LEN(values);
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1070:23: note: expanded from macro 'RARRAY_LEN'
#define RARRAY_LEN(a) rb_array_len(a)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
compiling pg_type_map.c
compiling pg_type_map_all_strings.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_class.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_column.c
pg_type_map_by_column.c:161:52: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return dec_func( p_coder, RSTRING_PTR(field_str), RSTRING_LEN(field_str), 0, fieldno, enc_idx );
               ~~~~~~~~                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1007:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_type_map_by_column.c:161:52: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return dec_func( p_coder, RSTRING_PTR(field_str), RSTRING_LEN(field_str), 0, fieldno, enc_idx );
               ~~~~~~~~                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1008:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
pg_type_map_by_column.c:230:17: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        conv_ary_len = RARRAY_LEN(conv_ary);
                     ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/EvanRoberts/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1070:23: note: expanded from macro 'RARRAY_LEN'
#define RARRAY_LEN(a) rb_array_len(a)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
compiling pg_type_map_by_mri_type.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_oid.c
compiling pg_type_map_in_ruby.c
compiling pg_util.c
pg_util.c:119:24: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return (char*)out_ptr - out;
        ~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle
ld: file not found: dynamic_lookup
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

I can't work out where to start, I've googled and Stackoverflow searched "implicit conversion loses integer precision" and no real results I can work with. I think sql is having trouble perhaps converting my database to sql from the standard database managment from rails, perhaps? Can anyone help here

Comment: The warnings do not fail the compilation. Your problem is `ld: file not found: dynamic_lookup`. Almost certainly relevant: [Rails 5: trying to bundle install end getting error with pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252222/rails-5-trying-to-bundle-install-end-getting-error-with-pg-gem)

Answer (score 3):

Those are all just warnings. Your error is at the bottom:

```
ld: file not found: dynamic_lookup
```

You're missing something in your system configuration, either the xcode tools (`sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` is usually the invocation to fix that), or you need to configure the path to pg_config, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27653949/271475).

Comment: If they were missing xcode tools, there would be no compilation warnings, as there would be no compilation...

Comment: My experience has been that an incomplete installation sometimes breaks in interesting ways (usually after an OS X upgrade), and a reinstallation does the trick. It's kind of the OS X equivalent of "have you tried turning it off and back on again" :)

Comment: Good point — though then the wording "xcode tools might be missing" is misleading.